# How to get all Redis hashes from specific subset in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, redis

So I have for example `users:username_1`, `users:username_2`, `users:other_username`. How can I get all users?

From google I learned that for this thing there is `KEYS` option but also it is not recommended to use. Only for debug.

SO is there any way to get all subset objects in NodeJS?

Comment: Do you want all the details of the users or just the user id? If you just want to load some ids I would make another structure, like a sorted set, while to load all user details maybe a lua script

Comment: @LiviuCostea I need each user as object of it's details.

Comment: Do you know the users in advance or you want all of them?

Comment: @LiviuCostea all. There are saved results from search. So I don’t know what exactly users there are.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipelining to send multiple [HGETALL](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall) for each user you want it loaded. This is how you can do it in node.js: [Batch commands](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#clientbatchcommands)
For finding out the users I suggest using another structure, I would go with a sorted set because you can take ranges faster than using a list. So everytime you create an user you do a ZADD on that sorted set, somethening like ZADD users:all x username_x. And before calling the batch with all the HGETALL you should do a [ZRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrange)

Comment: mongo and redis are not substitutes, you should use the best tool for your job

Comment: Mongo is more easier to use in current situation but I need the fastest solution